# Woocommerce rest api auth with token

Tags: json, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building a custom app to publish product from frontend. The problem is, I can log the user with the JWT Auth plugin who give me a token. But I can't use this one to create product.. The only thing who works is basic auth with username & password. But I don't want to pass the password for the request.

When I try with Postman the `Bearer auth token`, POST with `/wp-json/wc/v2/products`, I receive  this error : `woocommerce_rest_cannot_create`

A way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error might appear due to multiple  reasons , first 
don't use postman oAuth1.0  instead used the basic authintication . try replacing username and password with your consumer key.

**Modify your .htaccess to make the Basic auth work,

**paste this :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

second reason , missing variables with posting/curl/fetch your url or not filling the requirements of the rest api.
here is few tips which can help to resolve this issue .

OAuth tips
The OAuth parameters may be added as query string parameters or included in the Authorization header.

Note there is no reliable cross-platform way to get the raw request headers in WordPress, so query string should be more reliable in some cases.
The required parameters are: **oauth_consumer_key**, **oauth_timestamp**, **oauth_nonce**, **oauth_signature**, and **oauth_signature_method**. **oauth_version** **is not required and should be omitted**.

The OAuth nonce can be any randomly generated 32 character (recommended) string that is unique to the consumer key. Read more suggestions on generating nonces on the Twitter REST API forums.

The OAuth timestamp should be the unix timestamp at the time of the request. The **REST API will deny any requests that include a timestamp outside of a 15 minute window to prevent replay attack**s.

You must use the store URL provided by the index when forming the base string used for **the signature, as this is what the server will use. (e.g. if the store URL includes a www sub-domain, you should use it for requests)**

You may test your generated signature using LinkedIn’s OAuth test console – leave the member token/secret blank.

Twitter has great instructions on generating signatures with OAuth 1.0a, but remember tokens are not used with this implementation.

**Note that the request body is not signed as per the OAuth spec, see Google’s OAuth 1.0 extension for details on why.**

If including parameters in your request, it saves a lot of trouble if you can order your items alphabetically.
**Authorization header is supported s**tarting WooCommerce 3.0.

**Please note that for current versions of WordPress, using the json_url_prefix filter no longer works.**

**On WordPress 4.7 (and using the REST API from the core instead of a plugin), this is what you have to do to change the API prefix.**

```
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', 'my_theme_api_slug'); 
function my_theme_api_slug( $slug ) { return 'api'; }
```

If this doesn't work straight away, you'll need to flush the rewrite rules. You can run this piece of code once to do so (don't leave it in your code so it runs everytime)

```
flush_rewrite_rules(true);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply ! the basic auth works for me. I wanted to auth with token because when creating product, I want the product author take the ID of the user. 
If I use consumer key, it will use the author ID of the user and not the user logged

Comment: request api to get used id from the consumer key  ,

Comment: I created consumer key (admin) but in my app, the user #9 can create product. When creating product, the product have to take the ID 9 and not ME

It's for that I seach a way to auth with user token

Comment: yes , you can read clients user  with token's too  , there is some examples on that link

Comment: I read the link, and I the Step2:Use the token it's exactly what I did. But still the error woocommerce_rest_canno_create

Comment: can you provide your post link ?

Comment: I'm trying to create product with the woocommerce rest api in POST with the url `/wp-json/wc/v2/products`
I have a token generated by the plugin JWT Authentication for WP REST API

Comment: my friend , you need to debug post console , try to make same steps on this link please let me know how it goes , if all set i will edit my answer and add it in there 

https://liftcodeplay.com/2018/03/18/how-to-automatically-set-a-bearer-token-for-your-postman-requests/

Comment: hey , you can also integrate libraries which support the api for woocommerece and make it easier for you to get the job done , use this https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

Comment: Ok I found the issue. I used `rest_url_prefix` to change the wp-json in my custom url, but when I change it, it's doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Just see the date and time of the device you are using

I lasted 6 hours solving the problem I wasted my time and when I ran out of patience, by chance, I tried changing the computer's time, as it was different, the problem was solved